80-90s Movie. Boy who is a test subject in a lab, free hand solves a maze puzzle
Movie probably from the 80s or 90s. The MC, a young boy (10-13?) is apparently a test subject in a lab, he can't leave. While doing some thing for entertainment, (Playing computer game, reading a book, or tinkering with some broken piece of equipment, etc.) some of the lab technicians approach. (Can't remember if the tech were talking through a sealed window, or if the techs were just on the other side of the room.)
They want him to stop what he was doing to do some IQ type tests. The MC does not want to. (There is some obvious animosity between the boy and the techs.) They start insisting and threaten reporting his failure to do the test.
Eventually they hold up a piece of paper with a maze puzzle on it, saying "here do this one." (typical maze puzzle, start on the top edge and work out the correct path to the center, or find a path down to the bottom edge.)
The MC turns back to his desk grabs a pen and blank piece paper, and starts drawing on it. They tell him to come get the paper with the puzzle on it to do the test. But he instead hands them the paper he had been drawing on and says "I don't need it."
The tech looks at the the two pieces of paper, then holds them up to the light and stack them, and we see that they perfectly line up. The MC has free hand drawn the correct path for the puzzle on the blank piece of paper.
At first I thought this was the movie D.A.R.Y.L. (1985) - A Robot boy thinks he's human, escapes from a lab looking for his parents. Eventually he is captured again, and escapes a second time by stealing a SR-71 Blackbird jet.) But in doing some reviewing, I am pretty sure this scene did not appear in this movie.

As per this Reddit thread, could it be The Fly II?
I believe the first part of the maze scene is shown in this review at 2:12.

I found the film and indeed, he draws the route, which the scientist overlays.

Reddit post found via a query for film boy under observation solves maze on separate piece of paper

Yes that's it!!
